# $addToSet in mongodb is not working properly when fetching data from AWS

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, boto3, pymongo-3.x

I'm using Boto3 of AWS to fetch the security group data such as Security Group Name, Port, and Protocol which have inbound rule source as 0.0.0.0/0 IP and storing them in Mongodb, In the below format:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6102702a7f6ee984a6a11bfc"),
        "sgname" : "launch-wizard-4",
        "socket" : [
                {
                        "ports" : 443,
                        "portocol" : "tcp"
                },
                {
                        "ports" : 22,
                        "portocol" : "tcp"
                },
                {
                        "ports" : 80,
                        "portocol" : "tcp"
                }
        ]
}
```

Now, I'm using `$addToSet` to avoid duplication when I run the code again. But it is not working instead it is adding the same Port and Protocol again (not duplicating when I run the code more than twice):

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("6102702a7f6ee984a6a11bfc"),
        "sgname" : "launch-wizard-4",
        "socket" : [
                {
                        "ports" : 443,
                        "portocol" : "tcp"
                },
                {
                        "ports" : 22,
                        "portocol" : "tcp"
                },
                {
                        "ports" : 80,
                        "portocol" : "tcp"
                },
                {
                        "ports" : 80,
                        "protocol" : "tcp"
                },
                {
                        "ports" : 22,
                        "protocol" : "tcp"
                },
                {
                        "ports" : 443,
                        "protocol" : "tcp"
                }
        ]
}
```

Similar, thing is happening when I try to update using CLI. When the first time I run the cmd it is duplicating then it is not

```
db.sg.updateOne({"sgname": "launch-wizard-4"}, {$addToSet: {socket: {ports: 443, protocol: "tcp"}}})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
```

Here is my code:

```
import boto3
import pymongo
import ast
    
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.describe_security_groups()

client = pymongo.MongoClient('MONGO_URL')

sgname = []
protocol = []
ports = []
datas = []
data = {}
db = client.sg
col = db.sg

cur = col.find()
result = list(cur)

for sg in response['SecurityGroups']:
    for ip in sg['IpPermissions']:
        for cidr in ip['IpRanges']:
            if cidr['CidrIp'] == '0.0.0.0/0':
                sgname.append(sg['GroupName'])

sgname = list(set(sgname))

for sg in response['SecurityGroups']:
    for ip in sg['IpPermissions']:
        for cidr in ip['IpRanges']:
            if cidr['CidrIp'] == '0.0.0.0/0':
                if sg['GroupName'] in sgname:
                    log = {
                        "sgname": sg['GroupName'],
                        "socket": {
                            "ports": ip.get('FromPort','missing'),
                            "portocol": ip['IpProtocol']
                        }
                    }
                    datas.append(log)

sg_data = [ast.literal_eval(el1) for el1 in set([str(el2) for el2 in datas])]

for element in sg_data:
    sgname_name = element['sgname']
    socket_name = element['socket']
    if sgname_name not in data:
        data[sgname_name] = []

    data[sgname_name].append(socket_name)

new_lst = [{'sgname': key, 'socket': val} for key, val in data.items()] 

if len(result) != 0:
    for sg in response['SecurityGroups']:
        for ip in sg['IpPermissions']:
            for cidr in ip['IpRanges']:
                if cidr['CidrIp'] == '0.0.0.0/0':
                    col.update_many({"sgname": sg['GroupName']}, {"$addToSet": {"socket": {"ports": ip.get('FromPort','missing'), "protocol": ip['IpProtocol']}}})
    
    print("################################")

else:
    try:
        col.insert_many(new_lst)

    except pymongo.errors.BulkWriteError as e:
        print(e)
```

**Why this Duplication is Happening**

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly like due to field ordering.

When MongoDB [compares objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects) the field order matters, so `{port: 80, protocol: "tcp"}`, and `{protocol: "tcp", port: 80}` are not equal.

For an object with 2 fields, you could get 2 different orderings of the fields, so you can get 2 different objects with the same fields and values.

The mongod server [preserves field order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-field-order) in the documents it receives.

You will need to make sure the client is sending the fields in the same order each time in order to match on the objects.